# How to check screen locked in Rust?

Tags: macos, rust

I am using following code to check if the screen is locked on Mac:

```rust
pub fn is_locked() -> LockedState {
    let buf = Command::new("ioreg")
        .args(&["-n", "Root", "-d1", "-a"])
        .output();

    let output;

    match buf {
        Ok(buf) => {
            if buf.status.success() {
                output = buf.stdout;
            } else {
                return LockedState::Unknown;
            }
        }
        Err(_) => return LockedState::Unknown,
    }

    let v: Value;
    if let Ok(result) = Value::from_reader(Cursor::new(output)) {
        v = result;
    } else {
        return LockedState::Unknown;
    }

    let is_locked = v
        .as_dictionary()
        .and_then(|dict| dict.get("IOConsoleLocked"));

    match is_locked {
        Some(l) => {
            if let Some(b) = l.as_boolean() {
                return if b {
                    LockedState::Locked
                } else {
                    LockedState::Unlocked
                };
            }
            return LockedState::Unknown;
        }
        None => LockedState::Unknown,
    }
}
```

This works fine. But I would prefer to have a callback from OS rather than calling this function. I have checked core-foundation-rs crate but did not find anyhting relevant.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [this article that suggests the general mechanism to solve this issue](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-know-programmatically-if-a-mac-machine-is-screen-locked.733250/) as well as [relevant Rust bindings](https://docs.rs/cacao/latest/cacao/user_notifications/index.html).